# How to get SSL Observatory to use Tor?

Tags: windows, tor, https-everywhere

I just downloaded [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) and it's running great. However, I want to enable it all going through Tor (as much as it can via the configuration dialogue). However, that option is greyed out. I have the tor browser, what would I do to get this to work?

Here's the configuration prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Tor Ticket #8222](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8222) :

> "Check certificates using tor for anonymity" should really be "only
>   check certificates using Tor for anonymity". If it's unchecked, it
>   means the observatory will use a direct SSL connection if it cannot
>   find Tor.
>
> That option will be greyed out if HTTPS Everywhere failed to
>   successfully identify a method for making requests through Tor when it
>   started. But if Tor is installed or running or works correctly on a
>   future browser startup, the observatory will switch to using Tor at
>   that time, even if this option is unchecked.

This option should then be available and not greyed-out when Tor is running.
If that is not the case, update to the latest Tor and Tor browser versions,
and if this still arrives, then you could open a new support ticket.

However, you are safe even when the option is greyed, since the communication
with the EFF is encrypted.

As far as I know, the Tor browser already contains HTTPS Everywhere
and SSL Observatory, so you do not need to install the Firefox add-on.
SSL Observatory is off by default though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very well put, and interesting ticket. I still can't enable it on the TBB via Linux so I might have to open a ticket there.

Answer (score 1):

### Prelude

[SSL Observatory](https://www.eff.org/observatory) is a feature of [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/HTTPS-everywhere) exclusive to [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), currently.

---

### Solution

1. After installing HTTPS Everywhere, press `yes` to accept.

[image: First slide]

2. Check and see if the option is immediately available, if not, continue...

[image: Second Slide]

3. Open the Tor Browser and click on `SSL Observatory Preferences`.

[image: Third Slide]

4. ***Within the Tor Browser,*** enable the `Use the Observatory?` option.

[image: Fourth Slide]

5. ***Completely exit all windows of Firefox, and then reopen*** and enable the `Use the Observatory?` option.

[image: Fifth Slide]

Comment: Not working for me. It's stilled grayed out on the tor browser 5.0.1

Comment: Giving the bounty to this question because it did what I asked for; HOWEVER, I cannot get it to work and the other one explains what it is thus it's more of what I was looking for pre-bounty.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Privacy-Handbuch](https://www.privacy-handbuch.de/handbuch_21f1.htm). There's an undocumented way of enforcing socks settings on HTTPSEverywhere by editing Firefox's ´about:config´ database.

1. put `about:config` in Firefox's URL bar
2. and enter the data for your tor socks proxy as defined in the `torrc`
   (the standard tor (not tbb!) is using port 9050)

   Preference Name       Value

   `extensions.https_everywhere._observatory.proxy_type` = `socks`
   `extensions.https_everywhere._observatory.proxy_host` = `127.0.0.1` (localhost)
   `extensions.https_everywhere._observatory.proxy_port` = `9050`

I tested the settings for me, with the `netstat -a` command (in the windows command line). Unfortunately, the Observatory settings window doesn't show/indicate that HTTPSEverywhere is using tor (but netstat show's the connection).